# java int field let empty

Tags: java, netbeans

I was wondering if it was possible, in Java, to let  a field expected to be filled with an integer (such as in a JTable), empty. I mean something like `" "` for the Strings. I tried with null but it's not allowed for integers. Of course, I could put a default value `s.a. 0` but I don't want. Could you please help me?

Comment: but why dont you want?? take a look at default values in primitives and objects....

Comment: instead of int use Integer if you want null

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not necessary to assign a value when a field is declared. Fields that are declared but not initialized will be set to a reasonable default by the compiler (i.e. *0* for numeric types and *null* for objects).

For local variables the compiler never assigns a default value to an uninitialized local variable. So you must do this manually because in Java you cannot use a local variable that might be **uninitialized**, where 
"Uninitialized" means the variable might not have been set to anything.

You can set your variable as needed:

-Object can be set to null;

-Integer can be set to 0, `Integer.MAX_VALUE` or `Integer.MIN_VALUE`.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a custom [TableCellRenderer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/table/TableCellRenderer.html) that can display an empty String ("") when the int value in that column hasn't been set.

More detail here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender

Comment: How do you know if an `int` has not been set?

Comment: As http://stackoverflow.com/users/6931023/ravikant-sharma has said, the OP can use Integer instead of int.  Alternatively, depending on whether or not zero is a meaningful value in the OP's context, that can also be used to determine whether or not the value has been set.

Answer (score 0):

In Java 8 they have introduced the [OptionalInt class](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/OptionalInt.html) for this purpose. It has methods to test whether it has a value at all. But the most useful are the methods that return any value if present and let you specify what to do when there is no value specified. Depending on what kind of action your logic requires when no value is entered you can use one of the methods orElse(), orElseGet() or orElseThrow().